# Ruby Divide Always Returning Zero in Rails Axlsx Export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I cannot for the life of me figure out why dividing isn't working in this Aslsx export. I can add, subtract, multiple and do modulus division fine, but when I try to do `answer_number / question_number` it is always coming out as 0. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Works spitting out the `answer_number` times the `question_number`:

```
@survey.questions.each do |question|
        question_number = Choice.where(question_id: question.id).length
        question.answers.each do |answer|
            answer_number = Choice.where(answer_id: answer.id).length
            sheet.add_row [answer_number, question_number, answer_number * question_number]
        end
    end
```

Doesn't work - spits out 0:

```
@survey.questions.each do |question|
        question_number = Choice.where(question_id: question.id).length
        question.answers.each do |answer|
            answer_number = Choice.where(answer_id: answer.id).length
            sheet.add_row [answer_number, question_number, answer_number / question_number]
        end
    end
```

I also thought that maybe it was doing some sort of rounding down when the number was less than 0, but this doesn't seem to work either (the end goal is to get the percent of each answer chosen):

```
@survey.questions.each do |question|
        question_number = Choice.where(question_id: question.id).length
        question.answers.each do |answer|
            answer_number = Choice.where(answer_id: answer.id).length
            sheet.add_row [answer_number, question_number, answer_number / question_number * 100]
        end
    end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is division in Ruby returning an integer instead of decimal value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502761/why-is-division-in-ruby-returning-an-integer-instead-of-decimal-value)

Comment: You need a float... `answer_number.to_f`

Comment: Yep.  I'm an idiot.  I knew it was something easy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since both numbers are integers, ruby is doing integer division, which ignores remaining fractions, and I would guess all your divisions are returning numbers between 0 and 1, so the answer is always 0, to avoid that one of the both numbers should be a float so like @mtm suggested, add a `to_f` function to either of the numbers