# Rails - decimal not displaying in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following object -

```
Reckoner Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reckoners".* FROM "reckoners" WHERE
  "reckoners"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
=> #<Reckoner id: 2, group: "test FTEProrated", description: "try new calc", 
     leave: 28, abscence: #<BigDecimal:7fab221cf438,'0.1E2',9(27)>,
     created_at: "2014-10-06 15:56:10", updated_at: "2014-10-06 16:14:32",
     FTEProRated: #<BigDecimal:7fab221ca1e0,'0.0',9(27)>>
```

If I've done my calculation correctly, FTEProRated should be about 0.8 - but it's being displayed as 0.0. Where am I going wrong?

The calculation is carried out in the controller before the object is saved -

in update -

```
pro_rate_this @reckoner
```

...

```
def pro_rate_this(reckoner)
  reckoner.FTEProRated = (260-reckoner.leave)/260
end
```

when I change the calc to test what's being saved, it all seems okay - for example, this -

```
def pro_rate_this(reckoner)
  reckoner.FTEProRated = (260-reckoner.leave)
end
```

gives a value of 232 when reckoner.leave == 28. It's only when the value becomes < 1 that it seems to be a problem, though that could be coincidence.

Comment: how are you displaying it?

Comment: just as `<%= @reckoner.FTEProRated %>` in a view

Comment: Is `FTEProRated` a column from your database? If so, what is the column type? If not, please show us the code that calculates/assigns it.

Comment: Where is the calculation?

Comment: thanks all - have updated the question as suggested. Hi @lurker - yep I saw that too, but the result of the calc on paper is 0.8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is division in Ruby returning an integer instead of decimal value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502761/why-is-division-in-ruby-returning-an-integer-instead-of-decimal-value)

Comment: Hi Brad - have just had a look, and it sort of is - casting the calculation .to_f fixes the problem, but that's not the accepted answer on the question you linked to. What's the form in this circumstance? Should I answer the q myself?

Comment: It's the most highly upvoted answer, FWIW. It's basically the same solution, just a different approach, anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Math... make sure you're dividing by floats if you want your answer to be a float.

```
def pro_rate_this(reckoner)
  reckoner.FTEProRated = (260-reckoner.leave)/260.0
end
```

See the denominator there? Just add that `.0` to the `260` and report back.