# Division on rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a hard time on thinking what should I do with this problem. I'm dividing the two numbers and expecting a non-whole number answer. Meaning to say it should be on decimal format. But unfortunately it answers a whole number. 
example: 5 / 2 = 2

```
 s.apts =  sum_pts.to_f / sum_game.to_f
```

Comment: @YuHao it's not working on me. That's why I'm asking a help.

Comment: Provide a simple example of `sum_pts` and `sum_game` so that is can be reproduced.

Comment: the answer should be 2.5. But it is 2 on my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tell Ruby you are doing non-integer division, by writing the problem as "5.0 / 2.0"

See:

[Why is division in Ruby returning an integer instead of decimal value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502761/why-is-division-in-ruby-returning-an-integer-instead-of-decimal-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = 5.0
b = 2.0
puts a / b
```