# How does Ruby interpret exponents when using integers vs floats?

Tags: ruby, math, exponent

Here's an illustration of what I'm asking about:

[image]

I'm just curious about how Ruby is interpreting these problems, which are clearly different as far as Ruby is concerned. I became curious when I was trying to write a simple math problem without using floats and noted that Ruby would read Floats differently than their Integer counterpart (perhaps 1/2 *isn't* 0.5's counterpart as far as Ruby is concerned, but that's part of what I'm asking here: why not?).

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `17424 ** 1 / 2` is interpreted as `(17424 ** 1) / 2`, which is just 17424/2
- `17424 ** (1 / 2)` is counter-intuitive because `1 / 2` is actually `0`, not `0.5`. This is because when you divide integers, the result's decimal is truncated. You can change one of the operands (or both) to a float to fix this: `17424 ** (1.0 / 2)`

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense to me now.

Answer (score 3):

```
17424 ** 1 / 2
    17424  / 2
         8712


17424 ** (1/2)
17424 **   0
      1
```

`/` of two integers is an integer. See also: [Why is division in Ruby returning an integer instead of decimal value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502761/why-is-division-in-ruby-returning-an-integer-instead-of-decimal-value)