# Why a simple calculation returns different result in ruby

Tags: ruby, math, calculator, irb

I'm not an expert in maths but the following operation gives a different result in ruby than in any other language or calculator I've tried:

**Ruby:**

```rb
(289 / 30 * 30) - (149 / 30 * 30)
=> 150
```

**Rest of the world:**

```
(289 / 30 * 30) - (149 / 30 * 30)

140
```

An explanation is greatly appreciated

Comment: This isn't just Ruby, this is many programming languages where numbers without decimals are treated as integers. If you go through the math, but after each operation you remove the fractional part of the result, you'll get 150.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the data type [ruby uses for dividing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502761/why-is-division-in-ruby-returning-an-integer-instead-of-decimal-value), `int` is missing the fractional part of the result.

In Ruby :

```
289 / 30
=> 9
9 * 30
=> 270
289.0 / 30
=> 9.633333333333333
```

In Python (for example):

```
>>> 289 / 30
9.633333333333333
>>> 9.63333 * 30
288.9999
```

Answer (score 2):

This is integer math for you. 289/30 is equal to 9. By the way, same is in Python if you use `//` for integer division.

```
(289//30*30) - (149//30*30) = 150
```